# Jquery Cookie plugin and redirect

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I have the following code which works but dosent perform as expected:

```
$(".switch_org").click(function(e){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');        
    var orgID = id.split("_");

    e.preventDefault();

    $.cookie('current_organisation', orgID[1], { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    window.location.replace("index.php");

});
```

The **cookie is set which works fine** but the page is **not redirected to index.php** it just reloads the same page. Am I doing something wrong? Is there an additional step I can add so that it does redirect to index.php?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use window.location.replace, directly assign the value to

`window.location`

or

```
windows.location.href
```

Comment: I did try those, I tried them again, still just reloads the same page with the new cookie set.